# Why std::unique_ptr does not explicitly require a noexcept Deleter?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, noexcept, exception-safety

The documentation says that Deleter should be:

- nothrow constructible
- nothrow callable (because it's called from `~unique_ptr() noexcept`
- nothrow destructible (for the reason above)

My question is why `uniqut_ptr` is defined to allow a `Deleter` that may throw. E.g. the following `Deleter` is allowed by all `unique_ptr` constructors:

```
struct BadDeleter
{
    BadDeleter() noexcept(false) {}
    ~BadDeleter() noexcept(false) {}
    BadDeleter(const BadDeleter&) noexcept(false) {}
    BadDeleter(BadDeleter&) noexcept(false) {}
    BadDeleter(BadDeleter&&) noexcept(false) {}
    void operator()(char* p) const noexcept(false) {
        delete p;
    };
};
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/izTXaw)

Comment: Where exactly does it say what you claim in the first sentence?

Comment: What documentation states this?

Comment: Constructors are [noexcept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr), reset is [noexcept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) and destructor is [defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/%7Eunique_ptr) without `noexcept(false)`. I don't see how under these definitions Deleter can throw.

Comment: If it throws then it's UB.  `noexcept` isn't part of the function signature so you can't check if the deleter is marked that or not.

Comment: noexcept is a part of the function signature, at least in C++14.

Comment: Ah, C++17.  I forgot they added it.  They might change `unique_ptr` then in a future standard.  When it was first made though you couldn't tell.

Comment: I'm not actually sure about my previous statement anymore: I tried the same [piece of code](https://ideone.com/EgkbQ6) with GCC and it compiles. Only fails with MSVS 2015 Update 3. Nevertheless, there are utility functions since C++11 to check whether noexcept is present. I would expect them to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard only defines the requirements on a `uniqe_ptr`'s deleter based on the `unique_ptr`'s operations.  While those requirements always say things like

> ~unique_ptr();
>   Requires: The expression get_deleter()(get()) shall be well formed, shall have well-defined behavior, and shall not throw exceptions.

the standard never explicitly specifies that the deleter must have a `noexcept` `operator()`.

I presume this wording was chosen to remain backwards-compatible with C++14.  In that standard, `noexcept` was not part of a function's signature, and adding that requirement in C++17 likely would have broken a lot of code where custom deleters were used without explicitly marking their operations as `noexcept`.

Comment: I hope when released compilers will at least warn about missing `noexcept`.